# Is this Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality correct?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

I am reading Theory of Probability and Random Processes
Book by Leonid B. Koralov. In the Lemma 1.28, the book said: If $E \xi_1^2$ and $E \xi_2^2$ are finite, then $E(\xi_1 \xi_2)$ is also finite and

$$E|\xi_1 \xi_2| \leq (E \xi_1^2 E \xi_2^2)^{1/2}$$

But the correct formula should be

$$|E(\xi_1 \xi_2)| \leq (E \xi_1^2 E \xi_2^2)^{1/2}$$

I use their method, and I get the correct formula which are consistent with online Wikipedia. Can anyone give a counter example to show the formula in the textbook is wrong?

Comment: Both are correct, why do you say the first is not correct?

Comment: @copper.hat But the first one is a weaker version, right?

Comment: Only notionally. $\xi_k$ has finite variance **iff** $|\xi_k|$ has finite variance. You have  $ |E(\xi_1 \xi_2)| \le E | \xi_1 \xi_2 |  \leq (E \xi_1^2 E \xi_2^2)^{1/2} $.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Cauchy-Schwarz inequality is true for $\sum|ab|$ since if we prove that $\left(\sum xy\right)^2<\sum x^2\sum y^2$ for $x_i, y_i\geq0$ for all $i$, then let $a_i=\pm x_i$ and $b_i=\pm y_i$ then $$\left(\sum x^2\right) \left(\sum y^2\right)=\left(\sum a^2\right)\left(\sum b^2\right)$$ and $$\sum xy=\sum|ab|\geq\left|\sum ab\right|$$
using $|a|+|b|\geq|a+b|$, so we have
$$
\sqrt{\left(\sum a^2\right)\left(\sum b^2\right)}\geq \sum|ab|\geq\left|\sum ab\right|.
$$